# How to read a txt file line by line in R/Rstudio？

Tags: r, text

Suppose I have a messy text file like the following for example

```
Today is a good
day, but I feel very tired. It seems like it is
going to rain pretty soon.
```

I want to read the txt file into R as a character vector exactly the way it appears as in the original text file. In other words, I want to have the first element of the character vector being the first line, second element of the character vector being the second line, etc, as below

```
char_vector[1] = "Today is a good"
char_vector[2] = "day, but I feel very tired. It seems like it is"
char_vector[3] = "going to rain pretty soon."
```

I have tried read.table and read.csv, but it's always the case that some lines join together as one line. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `readLines` function.

Answer (score 5):

```
char_vector <- readLines(filename)

 txt <- "Today is a good
 day, but I feel very tired. It seems like it is
 going to rain pretty soon."

 readLines(textConnection(txt) )
#   ---- teh screen output of three distinct character elements
[1] "Today is a good"                                
[2] "day, but I feel very tired. It seems like it is"
[3] "going to rain pretty soon."                    

char_vector <- readLines(textConnection(txt))

char_vector[1]
#[1] "Today is a good"
```

Comment: It seems like this gives a single character vector, in which each chuck is separated by a comma. Is there a way to allocate each chuck to an element of a character vector?. Thank you by the way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are seeing. I will show you what appears if you use a textConnection. Files behave the same as text connections.

Comment: @SmithBlack If this solved your problem, please click the check mark next to it so that it's recorded as an answer.  You'll get some points for it, and it helps keep track of which questions still need answers.

Comment: Sorry about that, still new to stackoverflow

Comment: @SmithBlack No need for the apology.  We know you're new.  Just bringing you up to speed on conventions.

Answer (score 1):

scan can do this.

```
scan( file="myfile.txt", what=character() )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems like this requires to know how many lines in the text. If I have a huge file, how should I do this without know how many lines in the txt file?